# blank transparent window on startup unity 15.04

Tags: unity, 15.04, launcher

starting off my computer I noticed an unknown blank transparent window:

[image]

what is this?

it also looks like some preferences I had set have been lost (a specific resolution for a second monitor and default CTR-ALT-T shortcut for Terminator); I tried `apt-get update` and `dist-upgrade` but the situation is still the same,

I'm running 15.04 and kernel  4.2.0-040200rc3-generic(upstream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that running `xprop` and selecting this blank window will help you to know which process creates it.